# Why is this future verb translated as a perfect? (John 2:17)

Tags: greek, john, grammar, new-testament

In both the Douay-Rheims and its source, the Vulgate, the word καταφάγεταί (future tense) is translated as a verb in the perfect tense.

> And his disciples remembered, that it was written: The zeal of thy house **hath eaten** me up.
>
> Recordati sunt vero discipuli ejus quia scriptum est: Zelus domus tuae **comedit** me.
>
> [John 2:17 (DR+LV)](http://www.drbo.org/drl/chapter/50002.htm)

Here is the original Greek.

> ἐμνήσθησαν οἱ μαθηταὶ αὐτοῦ ὅτι γεγραμμένον ἐστίν· ὁ ζῆλος τοῦ οἴκου σου **καταφάγεταί** με.*
>
> (My translation) His disciples remembered that it was written: The zeal of your house **will consume** me.
>
> [John 2:17 (NA28)](http://www.nestle-aland.com/en/read-na28-online/text/bibeltext/lesen/stelle/53/20001/29999/)

The question is quite technical and a bit pedantic, but it still baffles me, why would a verb which is clearly future tense be translated as a perfect?

Here is the parsing of καταφάγεταί on the Perseus [word study tool](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=katafa%2Fgetai%2F&la=greek&can=katafa%2Fgetai%2F0&prior=sou&d=Perseus:text:1999.01.0155:book=John:chapter=2:verse=17&i=1#lexicon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that Jerome translated the Greek verb καταφάγεταί into Latin as a perfect verb, but one of two other possibilities:

1. He recognized that John 2:17 was a quotation of Psa. 68:10,<sup>1</sup> and the LXX of Psa. 68:10 had κατέφαγέν (conjugated in the aorist tense), which of course is suitably translated into Latin by the perfect tense.<sup>2</sup>
2. The Greek manuscript of John 2:17 that he was reading had κατέφαγέ(ν).

Regarding the latter theory, there is *some* support, although the great majority of witnesses favor καταφάγεταί.

Constantin Tischendorf wrote,<sup>3</sup>

[image: Constantin Tischendorf, Critical Apparatus, John 2:17]

---

### References

Tischendorf, Constantin. [*Novum Testamentum Graece.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=o3hAAAAAIAAJ) Vol. 3, Part 1. Lipsiae: Hinrichs, 1884.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Rahlfs’ numbering
<sup>2</sup> cp. LXX v. Vulgate of [Gen. 31:15](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lxx/gen/31/15/t_conc_31015), etc.
<sup>3</sup> p. [760](https://books.google.com/books?id=o3hAAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA760#v=onepage&q&f=true)

Comment: Great answer! I will think on it for a bit and then probably accept.